# Counting presses to a UIButton

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UILabel` and a `UIButton` in a XIB, and I want the `UILabel` to reflect the number of times the user has pressed the `UIButton`, e.g. when I click the button, the label shows 1, when I click it again, it shows 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    static int count;
    count++;
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
}
```

Comment: of course you need to have some connections with the IB,  like an IBOutlet for label and button event connection with the method

Comment: `static int count;`, does that make it persist when the method is called again?  I mean why not just do `label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([label1.text intValue] + 1)];`

Comment: yes and it does more than that, by making count static the value of it will become 0 automatically .(something I remembered from my college days)

Answer (score 3):

Header (.h) file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SampleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;   
    IBOutlet UILabel * theLabel;
    int count;
}

- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Implementation (.m) file:

```
#import "SampleAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SampleAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    count = 0;
    theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)theButton:(id)sender {
    count++;
    theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

So basically:
- Create new window-based app with the name Sample
- Edit SampleAppDelegate.m and SampleAppDelegate.h
- Connect theLabel to the UILabel in Interface Builder
- Connect the UIButton to theButton in Interface Builder
- Finally hit Build and Run